# Is there a map of Silverymoon with every street named?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, maps

Is there a street map of Silverymoon, one with every street and alley named?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Are you looking for only original (eg, unmodified to add "homebrew" street names) maps from official sources?

Comment: It's possible that not all minor streets and alleys were ever named. Maybe they're referenced relative to other places.. i.e.: "The Wayward Sage's alley".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find one in public domain. However looking at:

https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Silverymoon

There is a link on there for Roads in Silverymoon, with a large printout and some time you might be able to get most major roads annotated. Every alley, I'm not sure about, as alleys are not always named in such settings. Cannot find reference to say that it's ever been fully mapped out cannonically.